# Ant Design Dynamic Form Validations

Tags: antd

Say I have a dynamic form like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-voice-zyy4m?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

How can I validate my users fields to ensure that there is at least one name is filled before user submit the form?

I try to add `rules` into the `Form.List` but it is not working.
Adding custom validator to the individual user component only allow me to have access to that particular name component so I can't check the length of the name array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manage to make it works by adding this to the `rules`:

```
  ({ getFieldValue }) => ({
    validator() {
      if (getFieldValue("users").length > 1) {
        return Promise.resolve();
      }

      return Promise.reject(
        "Please add at least 2 options"
      );
    }
  })
```

Check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-voice-34yh6?file=/index.js)